# cannot stat ‘env.yml’: No such file or directory - JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a codebase wherein I will use Serverless Framework to deploy resources and functions.

MY PROBLEM IS, I CANNOT PUT THE ENV.YML INSIDE THE REPO SINCE THERE ARE SENSITE DATA THERE. With that being said, I cannot deploy my resources and functionalities using JENKINS since Serverless needs the Env.yml to deploy. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Serverless means are you using AWS or which cloud provider ? Whichever provider it is, they should have an option to store the files or secrets right ?

Comment: Hello rootkonda, I'm using AWS as cloud provider. I'm a newbie on creating pipeline using jenkins and using serverless framework that's why I don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: ok then you have to find out how to store secrets in AWS store and then how to refer them as variables in your env.yml file. Try googling on that. After you tried something, in case if you are stuck you can let us know here

Comment: Hello @rootkonda, I'm still unable to work with AWS SSM Parameter Store even if I declared all the params in the serverless.yml

Error says it coudnt find env.yml in our jenkins pipeline.